# Unable to connect using PuTTY ssh

Tags: putty

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and have installed PuTTY.  I'm trying to connect, but the authentication fails because of an incorrect password.  But, the VM I'm connecting to doesn't have a password?

Here are the creds I'm trying to use:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 2222
Username: vagrant
Private key: c:/users/<username>/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

When I open PuTTY, I put in the above credentials and click open, at which  point it ask for the username and I enter 'vagrant', then it asks for the password, but there isn't a password, so I get access denied?

Not sure how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably better asked at http://superuser.com

Comment: Normally this is a symptom of the key authentication failing and it falling back on password authentication.  Putty has its own key format, is your key file in that format?  Puttygen is used to convert a key from the openssh format to Putty.

Comment: I've never used PuTTY before, so I'm not sure what format it expects.  I checked the private key file and it is a long encrypted string `----Begin RSA PRIVATE KEY----MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22W...etc....----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----`

Answer (score 4):

The "---Begin RSA PRIVATE KEY ...." key is not of a format that PuTTY uses.

- Use the program puttygen.exe (same place where the putty.exe program
  is) to "Load" the private key.
- Select "All Files (*.*)" from the filter to see the file c:/users/.../.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  and open it.  It will say that it has successfully imported foreign
  key....
- Then use "Save private key" option to save the loaded key
  into a *.ppk file.
- Then use that ppk file as the key file for "SSH |
  Auth" in PuTTY

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the opposite: using the putty proprietary .ppk format to configure the "config.ssh.private_key_path" which expects the SSH format.

You can also you the puttygen to convert from .ppk format to SSH format.